# Почему прогрес бар (зеленые квадратики) не отображаются на git hub, хотя commit залетает?

Tags: github

Коммит залетает, вот:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а прогрес бар не отображает, что сегодня были сделаны изменения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

буду очень благодарен, спасибо!

Comment: Потому что приватный репозиторий?

Comment: Спасибо, но все же я изменил на публичный, и также не отображается прогресс бар... Что это может быть? @andreymal

Comment: Возможно почта в коммите не совпадает с почтой на github, либо коммит не в основную ветку репозитория.